# c++ Constructor with Parameter as Private Member

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

Using something other than a basic constructor has been a problem for me for quite some time. The issue is this:

I am using a constructor like this

```
Table(const std::string& LoadState)
{
    ImageManager ImgMgr;
    ImgMgr.add_resource_directory("img/");

    if (LoadState == "Menu")
    {

    }
    else if (LoadState == "CardFlip")
    {

    }
    else if (LoadState == "Game")
    {

    }
}
```

This is to load different images depending on the second of the game you are in to ensure nothing is loaded that we do not need.

I am trying to implement this into the menu object

```
private:
    Table LaTable("Menu");
```

This has never worked, initializing inside private, which I guess I do not understand.

I tried:
    private:
        Table LaTable;

```
constructor
{
    Table temptable("Menu");
    LaTable = temptable;
}
```

The issue with this is that the image comes up as a white square.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to handle this?

Comment: This seems to be very specific (what are `Table`, `LaTable`, etc). But did you try to use the initialization list in the constructor?

Comment: Ya, I tried it based on MM's response. ;) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want create an object of `Table` as a member in a class. To call its constructor, use the constructor of that class. Do it something like this:

```
// For example for a class named Menu
class Menu
{
public:
    Menu() : LaTable("Menu") // <--- Here
    { 
    }

private:
    Table LaTable;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it! That's awesome. This whole thing with non-default constructors has been bugging me for a long time!! I knew it had to be something easy!